# Perfect Forwarding to async lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, perfect-forwarding, stdasync

I have a function template, where I want to do perfect forwarding into a lambda that I run on another thread. Here is a minimal test case which you can directly compile:

```
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

/**
 * Function template that does perfect forwarding to a lambda inside an
 * async call (or at least tries to). I want both instantiations of the
 * function to work (one for lvalue references T&, and rvalue reference T&&).
 * However, I cannot get the code to compile when calling it with an lvalue.
 * See main() below.
 */
template <typename T>
std::string accessValueAsync(T&& obj)
{

    std::future<std::string> fut =
        std::async(std::launch::async,
            [](T&& vec) mutable
            {
                return vec[0];
            },
            std::forward<T>(obj));

    return fut.get();
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    std::vector<std::string> lvalue{"Testing"};

    // calling with what I assume is an lvalue reference does NOT compile
    std::cout << accessValueAsync(lvalue) << std::endl;

    // calling with rvalue reference compiles
    std::cout << accessValueAsync(std::move(lvalue)) << std::endl;

    // I want both to compile.

    return 0;
}
```

For the non-compiling case, here is the last line of the error message which is intelligible:

```
main.cpp|13 col 29| note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >’ to ‘std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >&’
```

I have a feeling it may have something to do with how `T&&` is deduced, but I can't pinpoint the exact point of failure and fix it. Any suggestions?

Thank you!

EDIT: I am using gcc 4.7.0 just in case this could be a compiler issue (probably not)

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm right, but maybe C++ requires you to *explicitly* use `std::move` on objects having both copy and move semantics.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't phrase the question well. Let me edit. The short of it, is that I want both function instantiations to work, and they each do a different thing (one forwards the vector by passing a reference around, the other forwards by moving the rvalue reference each time).

Comment: Turns out that it works if you cast to a `(const std::vector<std::string> &)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way I understand it you cannot use a function through `async` that expects non-const lvalue references as arguments, because `async` will always make a copy of them internally (or move them inside) to ensure they exist and are valid throughout the running time of the thread created.

Specifically, the Standard says about `async(launch policy, F&& f, Args&&... args)`:

> (§30.6.8)
>
> (2) Requires: `F` and each `Ti` in `Args` shall satisfy the MoveConstructible requirements. `INVOKE(DECAY_COPY (std::forward<F>(f)), DECAY_COPY (std::forward<Args>(args))...)` (20.8.2, 30.3.1.2) shall be a valid expression.
>
> (3) Effects: [...] if policy & launch::async is non-zero — calls `INVOKE(DECAY_COPY (std::forward<F>(f)),DECAY_COPY (std::forward<Args>(args))...)` (20.8.2, 30.3.1.2) as if in a new thread of execution represented by a thread object with the calls to `DECAY_COPY()` being evaluated in the thread that called async. Any return value is stored as the result in the shared state. Any exception propagated from the execution of INVOKE (DECAY_COPY (std::forward(f)), DECAY_COPY (std::forward(args))...) is stored as the exceptional result in the shared state.
>   The thread object is stored in the shared state and affects the behavior of any asynchronous
>   return objects that reference that state.

Unfortunately, this means you cannot even replace the reference with a `std::reference_wrapper`, because the latter isn't move-constructible. I suppose using a `std::unique_ptr` instead of the reference would work (implying, however, that your function arguments will always live on the heap).

**(EDIT/CORRECTION)**
I was working on a related problem when I realized that `std::reference_wrapper` actually enables a workaround, although I claimed the opposite above.

If you define a function that wraps lvalue references in a `std::reference_wrapper`, but leaves rvalue references unchanged, you can pass the `T&&` argument through this function before handing it over to `std::async`. I have called this special wrapper function `wrap_lval` below:

```
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

/* First the two definitions of wrap_lval (one for rvalue references,
   the other for lvalue references). */

template <typename T>
constexpr T&&
wrap_lval(typename std::remove_reference<T>::type &&obj) noexcept
{ return static_cast<T&&>(obj); }

template <typename T>
constexpr std::reference_wrapper<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>
wrap_lval(typename std::remove_reference<T>::type &obj) noexcept
{ return std::ref(obj); }


/* The following is your code, except for one change. */
template <typename T>
std::string accessValueAsync(T&& obj)
{

  std::future<std::string> fut =
    std::async(std::launch::async,
           [](T&& vec) mutable
           {
             return vec[0];
           },
           wrap_lval<T>(std::forward<T>(obj)));   // <== Passing obj through wrap_lval

  return fut.get();
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  std::vector<std::string> lvalue{"Testing"};

  std::cout << accessValueAsync(lvalue) << std::endl;

  std::cout << accessValueAsync(std::move(lvalue)) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

With this change, both calls to `accessValueAsync` compile and work. The first one, which uses an lvalue reference, automatically wraps it in a `std::reference_wrapper`. The latter is automatically converted back to an lvalue reference when `std::async` calls the lambda function.

Comment: Thank you, makes sense. I guess the decay copy makes sure references don't get through, and copies them "defensively".